# PowerShell Regex - word with wildcards and commas

Tags: regex, powershell

Trying to do a replace on what I understand to be a simple operation but hitting a wall.

I can replace a word with a comma on the end:

```
$firstval = 'ssonp,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient,MfeEpePcNP,PRNetworkProvider'

($firstval) -replace 'webclient+,',''
```

> ssonp,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,MfeEpePcNP,PRNetworkProvider

But haven't been able to work out how to add a wildcard in the word, or how I'd have multiple words with wildcards proceeded by a comma, e.g.:

> w* client+,* fee*, etc

(spaces added to stop being interpreted as formatting within the question)

Played with a few permeations and attempted to use examples from other questions without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-replace` operator takes a regular expression as its first parameter.  You seem to be confusing wildcards and regular expressions.  Your pattern `w*client+,*fee*,`, though a valid regular expression, seems to be intended to use wildcards.

The regular expression equivalent of the `*` wildcard is `.*`, where `.` means "any character" and `*` means "0 or more occurrences".  Thus, the regular expression equivalent of `w*client,` would be `w.*client,`, and, similarly the regular expression equivalent of `*fee*,` would be `.*fee.*,`.  Since the string to be searched has comma-separated values, however, we don't want our patterns to include "any character" (`.*`) but rather "any character but comma" (`[^,]*`).  Therefore, the patterns to use become `w[^,]*client,` and `[^,]*fee[^,]*,`, respectively.

To search for both words in a string, separate the two patterns with `|`.  The following builds such a pattern and tests it against strings with a match  in various locations:

```
# Match w*client or *fee*
$wordPattern = 'w[^,]*client|[^,]*fee[^,]*';
# Match $wordPattern and at most one comma before or after
$wordWithAdjacentCommaPattern = '({0}),?|,({0})$' -f $wordPattern;

"`$wordWithAdjacentCommaPattern: $wordWithAdjacentCommaPattern";
# Replace single value
'webclient', `
# Replace first value
'webclient,middle,last', `
# Replace middle value
'first,webclient,last', `
# Replace last value
'first,middle,webclient' `
    | ForEach-Object -Process { '"{0}" => "{1}"' -f $_, ($_ -replace $wordWithAdjacentCommaPattern); };
```

This outputs the following:

```
$wordWithAdjacentCommaPattern: (w[^,]*client|[^,]*fee[^,]*),?|,(w[^,]*client|[^,]*fee[^,]*)$
"webclient" => ""
"webclient,middle,last" => "middle,last"
"first,webclient,last" => "first,last"
"first,middle,webclient" => "first,middle"
```

A non-regex alternative you might consider would be to split your input string into individual values, filter out values that match certain wildcards, and reassemble what's left into comma-separated values:

```
(
    'ssonp,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient,MfeEpePcNP,PRNetworkProvider' -split ',', -1, 'SimpleMatch' `
        | Where-Object { $_ -notlike 'w*client' -and $_ -notlike '*fee*'; } `
) -join ',';
```

By the way, you used the regular expression `webclient+,` to match and remove the text `webclient,` from your string (looks like the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order\ProviderOrder` registry value).  Just a note that, with the `+`, that will search for the literal text `webclien` followed by 1 or more occurrences of `t` followed by the literal text `,`.  Thus, that will match `webclientt,`, `webclienttt,`, `webclientttttttttt,`, etc. as well `webclient,`.  If you are only interested in matching `webclient,` then you can just use the pattern `webclient,` (no `+`).

Comment: Thanks bacon that's exactly what I'm looking for, and yes that is the registry entry I'm looking at. How about if I wanted to look for both words at any position in the string?

Comment: @J1raya Please see my edit for how to search and replace both words in an input string.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `-split` is also a regex operator

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Good point.  I meant to include the `SimpleMatch` option of `-split`...but didn't.  `'ssonp,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient,MfeEpePcNP,PRNetworkProvider'.Split(',')` would be another truly non-regex substitute.

Comment: Thanks very much, a lot of very helpful information.